# Python ошибка на сервере при отправке запроса

Tags: python, requests

Отправляю гет/пост запрос на сайт, который защищен Qrator'ом. Копирую запрос из браузера, получаю ответ 200. Запускаю этот же самый скрипт на VPS Ubuntu 20.04, получаю ответ 401. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: по всей видимости QRATOR считает что запрос с мака или винды не представляет такой же угрозы как и запрос с сервера под управлением Linux. Плюс в вашей сети (я про пул ip-адресов вашего хостинга) очень даже может быть немало всякого интересного в виде ботов, краулеров и прочих игрушек, которые QRATOR не жалует, а может и в черном списке содержит.

Comment: + ко всему запрос из браузера и запрос из python скрипта - это таки разные совершенно вещи, которые QRATOR тоже видит

Comment: А что мне в таком случае делать? Я бы сказал, что это вопрос жизни и смерти.

Comment: для начала определитесь: вас куратор из-за скрипта или из-за сети не пускает. Если из-за скрипта, то смотрите чего в вашем запросе не хватает(заголовков, куков, ...поддежки JS клиентом может быть?)...в крайнем случае селениум попробуйте. Если из-за сети - то ищите адрес с которого вас пустят...ну и вы должны понимать, что если вы будете заметно напрягать сайт запросами, то ваш бан куратором - это всего лишь вопрос времени.

Comment: Ну, если у меня на локалке запрос возвращает код 200, а на сервере этот же самый скрипт - 401 (магия какая-то просто), то скорее всего из-за сети. Но у меня у хостинга только 1 ip адрес

Comment: ну я то наверняка этого не знаю.  вы можете делать запрос в браузере на рабочем компьютере, а проверять скрипт на сервере (это не смешно, отвечающие с этим ежедневно со стороны авторов вопросов сталкиваются)

Comment: `магия какая-то просто` -  тут как раз таки никакой магии. попробуйте тестовый период на других хостингах взять, попробуйте поработать с прокси и с VPS

Comment: Видимо куратору не нравился Линукс, потому что на Windows Server все работает...

Comment: очень в этом сомневаюсь.

Comment: из того что удалось найти за минуту: на Linux работает 96,5% веб-серверов. Данные эти старые и сейчас эта цифра скорее всего еще больше. Так что дело тут как раз таки в том, что он наоборот не видит никакой серьезной угрозы со стороны Windows)

Comment: Но реальность скорее всего в том, что у вашей сети(вашего хостинга) скорее всего плохая карма